# How Kurus in mahabharata were considered Kshatriyas when they were descendants of rishi vedvyas (a Brahmin)?

Tags: mahabharata, itihasa

With due respect, On what account were the Kuru lineage after Dhritrashtra and Pandu considered Kshatriya varna in Mahabharata when Dhritrashtra and Pandu themselves were born from a brahmin sage vedvyas ?

Comment: Where did you read that kurus from Dhritrashtra and Pandu were sons of Vyasa? Do you mean why Dhritrashtra and Pandu were Kashtriyas when they were sons of Vyasa?

Comment: @YDS please find the reference below :https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mahabharata/d/doc118371.html

Comment: @user19357 - The reference clearly reads Dhritrashtra and Pandu begotten by Vyasa

Comment: @Carmensandiego namaste ! I have tried to rephrase the question and its now under review. I was trying to ask that since dhritrashtra and pandu were born from a brahmin seer then how they and their respective lineages were  considered Kshatriyas instead ?

Answer (score 5):

From the the link of [this section of Adi Parva of Mahabharata](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mahabharata/d/doc118371.html) which OP provided in comments:

> In a former millennium, Parashurama, killed Kartavirya Arjuna in
> battle for the sin of slaying his father. Not only did he kill the
> followers of Kartavirya Arjuna, but he destroyed the entire kshatriya
> race twenty-one times. When the earth was devoid of great warriors,
> the queens approached the great rishis and procreated children by them
> and thus the kshatriya race was revived. Therefore, a purified
> brahmana should be invited with an offer of wealth, and let him raise
> children by the wives of Vicitravirya.

So, it's clear that kshatriya race was procreated by rishis/brahmins long back also.

This was due to a practice known as [Niyoga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niyoga).

---

There are [12 kinds of sons](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201544.html) and son born using the Niyoga practice known as kṣetraja son:

> यस्तल्पजः प्रमीतस्य क्लीबस्य व्याधितस्य वा ।
>
> स्वधर्मेण नियुक्तायां स पुत्रः क्षेत्रजः स्मृतः ॥ १६७ ॥
>
> If a son is born of the wife of a man, either dead or impotent or diseased, by one who has been duly ‘authorised,’—that son is declared to be ‘kṣetraja’ ‘soil-born.’ ~[Manu Smriti 9.167](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201546.html)

---

From above references, it's clear that even though Dhritrashtra and Pandu were biological sons of Vyasa but still they would be considered **kṣetraja sons** of Vicitravirya due to Niyoga practice and would be considered kshatriyas ultimately.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.